# Product Process Order

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to make a simple process order like :
You filled an order for 1 antacid for a total of $5.33
You filled an order for 3 sour bites for a total of $6.99

My code is:

```
total = 0

def process_order(x_list):

    for x in len(x_list):
        print(f"You filled an order for{x[1]} {x[0]} for a total of {x[1]* x[2]}")
x = [("oranges", 4, 3.22),("gummy bears",1,1.99),("sour bites", 3, 2.33), ("antacid", 1, 5.33)]

while(len(x)>0):
    process_order(x)

print("Total price: ${:.2f}".format(total))
```

But I got error

TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable

Comment: Use pythonic way: `for item in items` and it will solve your problem. In your case you can use `for item, quantity, price in items: print(f'You filled an order for {quantity} {item} for total {quantity * price}')`

Comment: Use `for x in x_list` instead of `for x in len(x_list)`.

Comment: `while(len(x)>0)` is infinite, `len(x)` never changes

Comment: Your loop in the `process_order` method: `for x in len(x_list):` loops `x` as an integer from 0 to 3. When you do `x[1]` (or any other subscript) you are triyng to subscript an `int`.

Comment: Function name `process_order` gives an idea, that only one order has been processed. so it's not a good idea to process many orders there at once. Moreso, if you return an order total from this function, you can sum over it afterwards to have total: `total = sum(map(process_order, orders))`. This will save you a lot of time to improve your functions while line with counting total still be the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I understood, this seems like the code you want:

```
total = 0

def process_order(x_list):
    global total
    for x in x_list:
        print(f"You filled an order for {x[1]} {x[0]} for a total of {x[1]* x[2]}")
        total = total + x[1] * x[2]

    return

x = [("oranges", 4, 3.22),("gummy bears",1,1.99),("sour bites", 3, 2.33), ("antacid", 1, 5.33)]

process_order(x)
print("Total price: ${:.2f}".format(total))
```

**Output**:

```
You filled an order for 4 oranges for a total of 12.88
You filled an order for 1 gummy bears for a total of 1.99
You filled an order for 3 sour bites for a total of 6.99
You filled an order for 1 antacid for a total of 5.33
Total price: $27.19
```

You need to define `total` as a global variable to get a overall total of the prices. Also, you can iterate through the list in python, as `for list_element in list`. If you want to make a function, it needs `return` statement at the end. In this case, what you have to do is to add each prices to `global variable`, and print out the process for each items, there's no need to return something.

Comment: Formatting: please, add more spaces to the body of `process_order `.

Comment: @EirNym Oops, I’ve fixed it! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You code is can be simplified with the same concepts minus the use of a defined function.  First thing to address, is your `while len(x) > 0` needs something to decrease the `len(x)` to end the loop.  For this we can use `.pop()`. This will remove the item at index , we will use `0`, and assign that to a variable `z`.  From here we can use your print statement unchanged, I used other formatting for preference.  And then we can add the total of each person to our running `total`.

```
x = [("oranges", 4, 3.22),("gummy bears",1,1.99),("sour bites", 3, 2.33), ("antacid", 1, 5.33)]
total = 0

while len(x) > 0:
    z = x.pop(0)
    print('You filled and order for {} {} for a total of {}'.format(z[1], z[0], z[1] * z[2]))
    total += z[1] * z[2]

print("Total price: {:.2f}".format(total))
```

> ```
> You filled and order for 4 oranges for a total of 12.88
> You filled and order for 1 gummy bears for a total of 1.99
> You filled and order for 3 sour bites for a total of 6.99
> You filled and order for 1 antacid for a total of 5.33
> Total price: 27.19
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Function name process_order gives an idea, that only one order has been processed. so it's not a good idea to process many orders there at once. Moreso, if you return an order total from this function, you can sum over it afterwards to have total: total = sum(map(process_order, orders)). This will save you a lot of time to improve your functions while line with counting total still be the same.

The sample code below:

```py
def process_order(order):
    """Process an order.

    Order is a tuple and contains 3 fields: name, quantity and price.
    """

    name, quantity, price = order
    total_price = price * quantity

    print(f"You filled an order for {]} {} for a total of {.2f}".format(
        quantity, name, total_price))
    return total_price

orders = [
    ("oranges", 4, 3.22), ("gummy bears", 1, 1.99),
    ("sour bites", 3, 2.33), ("antacid", 1, 5.33)]

total = sum(map(process_order, orders)) # can be rewritten with for loop
print("Total price: ${:.2f}".format(total))
```